# Run c program from QT

Tags: c, qt, user-interface

I have an application written in C language. Some how I need to create Qt frontend for it. I have linked c library to Qt project but I do not know how to call and execute c program in QT. Is there any command for that ?

Because I need to pass the output of c program to Qt application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#details) to launch your C program from a Qt application (no linking to C libraries required). Processing the output from that program would depend on what kind of output it produces (files, console output, etc.).